# adding <?php ?>into a <TD>

Tags: php, database

I'm still new a PHP so i'm trying to figure things out as I go.

There is one thing puzzling me.

```
    (LINE 51) <TD><?php

$data = file_get_contents("http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip={$s['ip']}&clean=true");

if($data == 'true') {
echo 'Online';
} else {

echo 'Offline';
}

?></TD>
```

This seems to shoot out the error that

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in home.php on line 53
```

Thanks in advance

PRIOR CODE @MattClark

```
<?php
                while($s = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
                    echo"

          <!-- Server Box - Table Method -->
                    <tr class='server'>
                       <td></td>
                       <td><a href='".$url."?p=server&s_id=".$s['s_id']."'>".$s['name']."</a></td>
                       <td><img class='default' src='".$url."images/countries/".$s['country'].".png' title='".$s['country']."' /> ".$s['country']." </td>
                       <td>".$s['type']."</td>
                       <td>".$s['votes']."</td>
                       <td><?php

$data = file_get_contents("http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip={$s['ip']}&clean=true");

if($data == 'true') {
echo 'The server is online';
} else {

echo 'The server is offline';
}

?></td>
                       <td></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Take a look at the previous `php` tag, I would venture to bet you missed a `;` at the very end.

Comment: An error on line 53 doesn't necessarily mean that's where the problem is.  It could be some line above that is missing `;` or scope not properly closed.

Comment: @MattClark `?>` implies `;`.

Comment: If you load this file into a PHP-aware IDE (e.g. NetBeans) it will likely be able to show you where the problem is straight away.

Comment: Change `if($data == 'true') {` to `if($data){`, won't fix your issue, in fact won't fix anything, but will look better. :D

Comment: This code appears to be complete, please post any prior PHP code.

Comment: @EdT. If anything it should be changed to `if($data === 'true') {`

Comment: Added extra code @MattClark

Comment: Woah.... and there be your errors... Give me a few while a type an answer...

Comment: First things first, you open a <?php tag, inside of a <?php tag... you never actually closed it.. you are just in an `echo`. Fix that, and see how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your syntax error you also have forgot `}` to while loop

```
<?php
while($s = mysql_fetch_array($sq)) {
echo"

<!-- Server Box - Table Method -->
<tr class='server'>
<td></td>
<td><a href='".$url."?p=server&s_id=".$s['s_id']."'>".$s['name']."</a></td>
<td><img class='default' src='".$url."images/countries/".$s['country'].".png' title='".$s['country']."' /> ".$s['country']." </td>
<td>".$s['type']."</td>
<td>".$s['votes']."</td>
<td>";

$data = file_get_contents("http://awebsite.com/status?server_ip={$s['ip']}&clean=true");

if($data == 'true') {
echo 'The server is online';
} else {

echo 'The server is offline';
}

?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<td>".$s['votes']."</td>
<td><?php
```

To this:

```
<td>".$s['votes']."</td>
<td>";
```

You have not finished your statement, the echo has not been closed, and you attempted to open a `<?php` tag, while still inside a `<?php` tag.